# Indpendence of Random variables in terms of characteristic functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence

In Rene Schilling's Brownian Motion , to prove Strong Markov Property, he uses a characterization of independence of a random variable $X$ and a set $A$ that $E(\exp(itX)\mathbf{1}_{A})=E(\exp(itX))P(A)$ .

I have never seen this characterization of independence before and I don't see how to prove it from usual notion of independence.

I tried characteristic functions , i.e. I know that $X$ and $\mathbf{1}_{A}$ are independent iff $E(\exp(i(tX+s\mathbf{1}_{A}))=E(\exp(itX))\bigg(P(A)(\exp(is)-1)+1\bigg)$ . But how do I show that
$E(\exp(itX)\mathbf{1}_{A})=E(\exp(itX))P(A)$ implies independence? . The converse that independence implies $E(\exp(itX)\mathbf{1}_{A})=E(\exp(itX))P(A)$ is clear.
Well to start with , to make it entirely precise, we should talk about the joint distribution on $\Omega^{2}$ and prove that the joint measure is equal to the Product measure.

Can anyone help me out with this?

**Edit:-** I was being stupid and I just solved it. Thanks for posting an answer though. I'll mark it as answer. We just use the assumption that $E(\exp(itX)\mathbf{1}_{A})=E(\exp(itX))P(A)$ and prove that the joint characteristic function factorizes

$$E(\exp(itX))\bigg(P(A)(\exp(is)-1)+1\bigg)$$

$$=P(A)E(\exp(it(X+s))-P(A)E(\exp(itX)) +E(\exp(itX))$$

$$=e^{is}P(A)E(\exp(itX)-P(A)E(\exp(itX))+E(\exp(itX))$$

$$=e^{is}E(\exp(itX)\mathbf{1}_{A})-E(\exp(itX)\mathbf{1}_{A})+E(\exp(itX))$$

$$=e^{is}E(\exp(itX)\mathbf{1}_{A})+E(\mathbf{1}_{A^{c}}\exp(itX))$$

$$\int_{A}\exp(itX+is)dP+\int_{A^{c}}\exp(itX)\,dP$$

$$=\int_{\Omega}\exp(i(tX+s\mathbf{1}_{A}))\,dP$$

$$=E(\exp(itX+is\mathbf{1}_{A})$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}E(\exp(i(tX+s\mathbf{1}_{A}))&=E(\exp(i(tX+s\mathbf{1}_{A}){1}_{A})+E(\exp(i(tX+s\mathbf{1}_{A}){1}_{A^{c}})\\
&=e^{is}E(\exp(i(tX){1}_{A})+E(\exp(i(tX){1}_{A^{c}})\\
&=e^{is}E(\exp(i(tX){1}_{A})+E(\exp(i(tX)(1-{1}_{A})).\end{align} Apply the given equation to $E(\exp(i(tX){1}_{A})$. Can you finish the proof now?